# non linear time scaling in dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I have a 16kkk * 10 dask df with all categorical cols and I run a function on it (calculate the likelihood of taget==1 for each category in each feature column). For 10 cols it can run in ~3 mins, but if I add 3 extra columns (combinations of some existing cols), it will run for ~15 mins. The time increase is much more dramatic than I anticipated and I'm not sure what to do: rewrite the function (which I did many times for this exact reason) or accept this increase in time.

I understand, in general, how dask df operates (many pandas df stacked horizontally). I tested increase in the number of rows and the time increase is much less severe: 10% of data - 40 sec, 100% data = 3 min.

Any suggestions why it might be? What should I look at first to try and improve the execution time.

Here is the main function I use right now:

```
def smoothed_likelyhood(df, alpha=1, verbose=False):
    """
    Discription:
        preprocess based on mean values of positive events in each category
    Args:
        df: [df] - df to encode
        alpha: [int/float] - regularization param. We can find it with CV
    Returns:
        encoded df, dict to encode user during prediction
    """

    if verbose:
        print(f'starting: smooth encoder')

    global_mean = df['target'].mean()
    smooth_dict = {}

    for c in [c for c in df.columns if c != 'target']:
        n_rows = df[c].value_counts()
        all_means = df.groupby(by=c)['target'].mean()
        temp_result = (all_means * n_rows + global_mean + alpha) / (n_rows * alpha)
        smooth_dict[c] = temp_result.compute().to_dict()
        df[c] = df[c].map(smooth_dict[c])
    
    return df, smooth_dict
```

I run a few benchmarks and the most time in the function is taken by the line:

```
smooth_dict[c] = temp_result.compute().to_dict()
```

I had a few other alternatives, without the explicit compute, with dict comprehension, but the time was the same. Apparently, because it would calculate dict anyway.
I also tried running not threads but multi processes for this function. It was said, MPs were better for dict, lists etc. But it took forever to run it, had to stop.

Any suggestion, observation, or advice is much appreciated.

ps. I also have a small reproducible code if anyone is willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will lead to a lot of improvement, but one bottleneck in your code is because the code is waiting for `.compute` to finish before proceeding to the next item in the loop. So here's one option for speeding it up a bit:

```py
# make sure this is imported to allow dask.compute
import dask

# code skipped

# run the loop without compute
for c in [c for c in df.columns if c != 'target']:
    n_rows = df[c].value_counts()
    all_means = df.groupby(by=c)['target'].mean()
    temp_result = (all_means * n_rows + global_mean + alpha) / (n_rows * alpha)
    smooth_dict[c] = temp_result

# now can compute
# note that the objects inside will still need to be transformed to_dict
smooth_dict = dask.compute(smooth_dict)

# now continuation of the loop
for c in [c for c in df.columns if c != 'target']:
    df[c] = df[c].map(smooth_dict[c].to_dict())
```

Comment: It now only takes 20 sec, instead of 3 mins with your refactoring, Sultan. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Great, didn't expect this much of a speed-up!